# How can I install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: software-installation, vmware

I need help installing VMWare player on my Ubuntu 12.10 system because I am having problems installing VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

Download the player from the VMware website:
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

The download will come through as a '.txt. file. Once you have the file, open the command prompt and go to the location that you downloaded the file to:

For example if you put it in your 'Downloads' directory you could issue:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

Then you will want to execute the script to do the install. You can do that with by issuing the following commands:

```
chmod +x <name_of_file>
./<name_of_file>
```

Where the `<name_of_file>` is the name of the VMware player txt file you downloaded.
This should start the installation wizard to install the program.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualbox` is easily installable using APT. Just with typing:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

in a terminal you can install virtualbox. If you are doing so, and still have problems ask another question and include the problem you are facing.