# How can I install VMware on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-installation, virtualization, vmware-player

How can I install VMware in Ubuntu 13.10? VirtualBox crashes the whole time or doesn't want to work 100%.

I've tried the solution in [How can I install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366283/how-to-install-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-12-10), but I get errors in terminal when I try the commands.

VMware can me used in the same way as VirtualBox, right? I want to install a different OS inside Ubuntu using VMWare.

Comment: [This post](
http://askubuntu.com/a/392736/231085) has instructions to install vmware player (with pictures!) in the answers section.

Comment: It would be better if you could post the exact errors you encounter when you try to install VMware Player.

Answer (score 7):

1. Download the bundle [from here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0) to your Downloads folder.
2. Open up the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Enter the following commands:

   ```
   cd Downloads 
   chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle 
   sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle
   ```
4. Follow the install GUI.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare is not packaged, but you can find detailed install instructions in the [Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware). I suggest you start by installing [VMWare Player](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player) and go on from there. If you have particular issues installing please post the error messages.

Comment: I've looked and tried the commands you suggested on the link, but struggle to install the program, it looks installed if looked at terminal. but I still don't have the program en the tools needed, also described in the link,to get all working. What else can I do? I do have the bundle that I downloaded from vmware's website. There a way to install it?