# VMPlayer installation error on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, kernel, vmware

when I try to install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I get the following error:

> Unable to build kernel module.

I saw in other similar questions that a suggested solution is to do the following:

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux 
sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h 
sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h 
sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

However, I don't have the last file, `version.h` although I have installed the linux headers but no luck.

I also tried to run

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

but it fails with the following message:

```
tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:40:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h:
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-44-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'
Unable to install vmmon
```

Is there any other way to install the missing headers?

EDIT 1

The screen-shots bellow show what I see after I complete the installation

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your errors don't occur for me with `VMware Player 6.0.1-1379776 X86-64` on `Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64`. It would be helpful if you could mention whether you are running a 32bit or 64bit operating system, what version number of Vmware Player you are attempting to install, and whether you have done any kernel upgrades.

**How To Graphically Install VMware Player 6.0.1-1379776 X86-64 on Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64:**

**Step #1:** Navigate to the directory you've saved VMware Player in.

[image: img1]

**Step #2**: Right click on the .bundle file and open the properties menu.

[image: img2]

**Step #3:** In the permissions tab check the box for "allow executing file as program".

[image: img3]

**Step #4:** Open terminal and type "sudo nautilus" as root privileges are needed.

[image: img4]

**Step #5:** Click "ok" on the error message regarding nautilus.
[image: img5]

**Step #6:** Navigate to the directory you saved the .bundle file in, right click, and choose "open" from the menu.

[image: img6]

**Step #7:** Choose "run" as it will allow for graphical installation.

[image: img7]

**Step #8:** Accept the Vmware Player End User License Agreement and click "next".

[image: img8]

**Step #9:** Accept the VMware OVF Tool Component For Linux License Agreement and click "next".

[image: img9]

**Step #10:** Choose appropriate update option to your liking and click "next".

[image: img10]

**Step #11:** Choose appropriate statistics option to your liking and click "next".

[image: img11]

**Step #12:** If you have a plus key you can enter it now, if not don't worry about it, and click "next".

[image: img12]

**Step #13:** Click "install".

[image: img13]

**Step #14:** The installation will begin, please wait for it to finish.

[image: img14]

**Step #15:** Click "close".

[image: img15]

**Step #16:** Search for "vmware player" in your unity search area. Click on "Vmware player".

[image: img16]

**Step #17:** VMware player will open and be ready for use. [You may need to run vmware player as root to download the vmware tools.]

[image: img17]

Comment: thanks for your long replay! My ubuntu is 12.04 LTS i386, and I'm usin the VMWare Player 2.5.5. I'll try what you posted now.

Comment: I added two screen-shost to my question to see what I get after I complete the installation. I upvoted either way for your effort

Comment: Are the screenshots you added from a 2.5.5 installation attempt or a 6.0.1 installation attempt? Did you remove your previous vmware player installation before attempting a the new one? Do you desire 2.5.5 rather than a new version?

Comment: I no longer have a 2.5.5 i386 installer, and vmware.com has disabled the download for that version. https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details/player_255_win/amRidGUqd2Jkampk#product_downloads

Answer (score 1):

How To Install VMware Player When Headers Need Building:

Step #1:

In terminal type: `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Step #2:

Right click on your `.bundle` file for vmwareplayer, check executable, and then double click to start the installation procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I have already done these steps but I still get the above errors.