# How do I install VMware?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, vmware-player

I need help to install vmware or vmplayer but I don't quite understand the written command to install it. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 12):

1. On the page of VMware Downloads find "VMware Workstation Player", click on download product and you will see a link to .bundle-file
2. In terminal type

   ```
   sudo sh /location/to/the/file.bundle
   ```
3. Follow the installer's prompts

---

There is an old **answer** with pictures available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/392736/276974) though it's a bit out of date as it's for 12.04 and Vmware Player 6.0.1 but that doesn't matter. It should be noted that it takes a different approach than listed here to execute the bundle.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer, as it seems to be a more straight-forward way of installing VMWare, vs other examples and suggestions.  Users should check for newer versions available.  At this time, **7.0** is stable and recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do this successfully. follow the instruction on the link below.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player

in entering the name of the backage, do not use spaces in between. e.g VMware 10.0.2.bundle (wrong) and VMware10.0.2.bundle (right)

Comment: These instructions did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04.